# Preloading images below the fold in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, preload

I have a button, that if clicked, show an image.  I'd like the image to preload before the button is clicked.  The button and image are below the fold.

At first, I was going to use the `Image` component's `priority` attr, but [the docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#priority) say:

> Should only be used when the image is visible above the fold.

So, then I looked at the `loading` attr, but [the docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#loading) say:

> This property is only meant for advanced usage. Switching an image to load with eager will normally hurt performance. ... We recommend using the priority property instead

So what should I use for preloading a below the fold image?

Comment: Use `priority`, it doesn't matter that image is above the fold or not. What you have cited is just a recommendation as preloading assets affects website's initial load time.

Comment: priority and loading do not preload the image if it is still not rendered (i.e. conditionally rendered at a press of a button)

Comment: For better performance you can use `lazyBoundary` to load that image below the fold. The image is still lazy loaded and will not hurt the performance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Image property `loading="eager"`

Like this:

```
<Image src={'/images/img.jpg'} loading="eager" priority={true} />
```